# YouTube as popup play on desktop version but not on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I am using below script to play YouTube video as a bootstrap Modal, It play video on desktop version but same fails to play on mobile devices such as iphone and iPad.

`YouTubeLoader.js`

```
// Load & insert into DOM Youtube iframe_api
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

/* Create Player */
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

  console.log('Api Loaded');

}

  $(".youtubeVideoLoader").each(function() {
    // Set the BG image from the youtube ID
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(//i.ytimg.com/vi/' + this.id + '/hqdefault.jpg)');

      // Click the video div
      $(document).delegate('#' + this.id, 'click', function() {
        // Vemos le id del video
        console.log(this.id);

        // Create new instance of player
        player = new YT.Player('videoModalContainer', {
          videoId: this.id,
          events: {
            'onReady': OpenModal,
            'onStateChange': console.log('Changed')
          }
        });

        // Show Modal
        function OpenModal() {
          $("#youtubeModal").modal({backdrop: "static"});
          // Set Highres
          player.setPlaybackQuality('highres');
          // Play Video
          player.playVideo();
        };
      });// /click

  }); // /each video

  // Add a Lisener to Modal CLose Button
  $('#CloseModalButton').click(function(){
        console.log('Stop Preset');
        player.destroy();
      });
```

HTML

```
<div  id="3WCMCeS7Na4" class="youtubeVideoLoader">
</div>
    <!-- Modal Template -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="youtubeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="CloseModalButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
          </div>
        <div class="modal-content">

          <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="videoModalContainer">

            </div>
          </div>
```

I have tried it with other video and i face the same issue as i initially thought it might be one video which is not playing due to privileges

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved removing following two lines of code.

```
 //player.setPlaybackQuality('highres');
 //player.playVideo();
```

It was not playing on mobile devices as Youtube has stopped the AutoPlay functionality of video. Not sure why it worked on desktop version...